# django 1.5 update ALLOWED_HOSTS failing SuspiciousOperation

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I have updated to django 1.5 and am getting the following message:

> SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): localhost:8000

I have tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, localhost:8000 in ALLOWED_HOSTS. I have also tried ['*'] all without success.

Anybody any ideas where I am going wrong? Works as expected with `DEBUG=False`

Comment: Give a try to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']`. Hope that helps.

Comment: What about a string: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = "*"`

Comment: Thanks both for responses, I have tried and just retried both the suggestions without success, I get the same suspiciousoperation. I am thinking that if "*" does not work then there must be something configured incorrectly elsewhere?

Comment: Please note that contrary to @alecxe comment above ``localhost`` will not work in ``ALLOWED_HOSTS`` - see regex for host sanity check https://github.com/django/django/blob/58d555caf527d6f1bdfeab14527484e4cca68648/django/http/request.py#L27

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I had deploy settings in a different file overriding the allowed_hosts in settings.py. Appologies missed this before posting. Thanks for the responses received.